# How to call function 200 times in 1 second

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

This code doesn't call function 200 times in 1 second, first time I get 167 calls, second time 201 but I don't get 200.

```
public Thread thread;
public Timer timer;
int i = 0;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   timer = new Timer(Mess);
   timer.Change(10000, 10000);
   thread = new Thread(Calc);
   thread.Start();
}

private void Mess(object state)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Call in on second : " + (i / 10).ToString());
   i = 0;
}

private void Calc(object obj)
{
   while (true)
   {
      i++;
      Thread.Sleep(5);
   }
}
```

Comment: What your code does is 'call my function every 5 milliseconds' - this could only work in the ideal world where executing the code takes no time at all - which is not possible. What you are trying to achieve is actually not possible at all on a typical OS - however smart your code will be, there's no guarantee that some other high-priority process won't hog the processor and prevent you from executing a single line of code during your 1 second.

Comment: Why not call it as fast as you can and stop when you hit 200?

Comment: @mcwyrm +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Its because of your scheduler wich manage the different threads in your processor. This process is not running all the time in your processor so strange behaviors can occur. 
Programs using threads are rarely deterministic (it's why you get 167 for the first time ans 201 in the second time)

Answer (score 1):

Because Windows is not a real-time operating system, it is difficult to achieve this kind of resolution.

The closest you are likely to get is by using the Windows API function [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is a high-resolution timer, but it still might not be high enough resolution for your purposes.

You may still like to try it though. It's awkward to call from C# because it uses a callback function which Windows expects to be a native method. It's possible though, and [here's an article on how to call it from C#](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=817).